# Accessing Google Cloud Pubsub over HTTP 2 using grpc and node js

Tags: publish-subscribe, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub, grpc-node

I am trying to use grpc with google cloud pubsub in nodejs but I am unable to understand how it works and how it is implemented there are no samples in nodejs and documentation is not clear for grcp.
There are only [function](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1) in documentation

I have seen many links but I found nothing

I don't understand:

1) I have to use which library to use its package in .proto file and how to require/install it?

2) Where do I have to give my projectId or service file path?

I want some guidance or it will be great if there are any samples in nodejs.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use @google-cloud/pubsub library for node.js? This way it should be much simpler to use. Which benefits of direct grpc usage you are trying to utilize?

Comment: I think HTTP means RESTful, which is different to grpc. Are you looking for examples of grpc like [Loading service descriptors from proto files](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node.html#loading-service-descriptors-from-proto-files) to access pubsub right?